# How to insert Adjustment record with Contract API

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to insert an adjustment record via the SOAP API using the following code.

```
Dim NewAdjustment As Adjustment = New Adjustment With {
    .ExternalRef = New StringValue With {.Value = "TEST1234"},
    .Description = New StringValue With {.Value = "1234TEST"},
    .[Date] = New DateTimeValue With {.Value = "12/20/2018"},
    .Details = {New AdjustmentDetail With {
        .BranchID = New StringValue With {.Value = "PRODWHOLE"},
        .InventoryID = New StringValue With {.Value = "18r.5"},
        .WarehouseID = New StringValue With {.Value = "RETAIL"},
        .Qty = New DecimalValue With {.Value = 100}
        }}
}

Dim InsertAdjustment As Adjustment = CType(soapClient.Put(NewAdjustment), Adjustment)
```

I get an error px.data.pcexception: Error: 'Branch' cannot be empty. Error: 'Post Period' cannot be empty. Error Inserting 'Receipt' record raised at least one error.

I'm guessing I need to fill those values but I'm not sure how to do that. I see them in the table but not the API interface. I'm new to Acumatica, so I'm guessing this is just something I'm missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To which screen you try to send Contract API request?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. With the contract API, shouldn't I be effecting the business objects rather than the screens? In this case, I'm trying to duplicate the logic that would be on IN303000. We are using it to keep inventory in sync with a legacy system during the conversion process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never seen the usage of the Date property as [Date], but that does not mean it will not work.  The Posting period is defaulted based on the value of the date property.  Make sure that the December 2018 posting period is open on the company that you are logged into with the API. I have seen this error from time to time when the accounting department does not open the period in a timely fashion.

The BranchID is defaulted based on the login parameters of the soapClient.  One thing to be aware of is that your API login user needs to have permissions to the BranchID being used, or you will definitely get an error about the Branch being invalid.

Depending on the Inventory costing methodology used by your company, Inventory Adjustments might require that they be processed against an inventory Receipt.  This can be tricky to figure out what to do, especially if you have never received anything for this Item in a new implementation, and you want to increase inventory levels.  For positive Adjustments in your business case, you might want to consider creating Inventory Receipts instead of Adjustments.  The entity is very similar to the Adjustments.  For negative Adjustments you might want to consider using Inventory Issues which is again, quite similar.

If you decide to use adjustments, you will have to search the Inventory Receipts for an appopriate Receipt number to use when populating the transaction details.  One for each line you insert.

Comment: BranchID from the login was my problem. Turns out the date thing was a bit of a misdirect. For what it's worth, setting the date does in fact work. Also, thanks for the info on the transactions. The person in charge of the conversion wants it done as inventory transactions (and again, this is all a temporary solution that will disappear several months down the road).